# What's the syntax to create nested if else statements with do's

Tags: haskell

So I am just getting the hang of Haskell and got stuck with the syntax for creating nested if-else statements with Do.
I am not sure, if I am supposed to use multiple Do's or if I can accomplish it all with just one. 
I am also not sure if I should use the return statement and if all the semicolons are necessary.

I tried adding and removing braces, return statements, semicolons, different indenting and do not know what else to try.

I get errors like "     • Couldn't match expected type ‘m0 (m0 b0)’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: a <- getVal
"

1. This is the kind of structure I am trying to build but it gives me errors. You can imagine the getVal functions as arbitrary functions, that return an integer :

   ```
   func :: Int -> Int
   func val = do {
      if val < 10
         then do {
             a <- getVal0;
             b <- getVal1;
             if (val+a+b) < 0
                then return 1
                else return 2}
         else if val > 10 
             then do {
                a <- getVal2;
                b <- getVal3;
                if (val + a +b) < 0 
                  then return 0
                  else return 1}
         else return 99;     }
   ```

An example of get val would be:

```
    getVal :: Int
    getVal  = 5
```

So this is what I want to happen :

If val is < 10, then get the value a with 2 parameters from getVal0 and get b from getVal1 . Then add val+a+b and if that is smaller than 0, return 1, else 2

If val is > 10, then get a from getVal2 and get b from getVal3. If val+a+b <0 then return 0, otherwise 1 .

If val is neither <10 or >10 ( val = 10) then return 99

Thanks for feedback and help!

Comment: what are `getVal0` and `getVal1`? But it looks like you are trying to use a `do` block where it is both unnecessary and invalid. `do` blocks are only for computations within a monad - `Int` is not a monadic value so you can't use a `do` block to calculate such a value.

Comment: Just added an explanation for the functions. You can imagine them as arbitrary functions that return an Int.

Comment: Why are you using the `{}`? The purpose of that syntax is to simplify machine-generated code not for normal people to use it... Anyway checkout [this wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures)

Comment: `do` doesn't do what you think it does. Ditto `return` and `<-`. This function needs none of those.

Comment: How would I then accomplish such kind of nested structure in haskell? I need to store multiple values and then make descision based on the stored values

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the `let ... in ...` syntax here.

Comment: Mh... starting to think I should have been using  Let

Comment: I tried writing an answer but this is too broad; requires explaining haskell syntax, purity, `do` notation, etc, etc. Even trying to fix this code block depends very much on the type of the made-up `getVal1`. Could you try asking just a single question, with an MCVE if you are still stuck?

Comment: @jberryman I think an answer that simply shows the correct way to use `let`, without getting into why `do` is inappropriate, would be sufficient. The OP commented that `getVal0` and `getVal1` are functions, so we can assume that something like `let a = getVal0 parm1 parm2 in ...` is the intent.

Comment: Hey I am fiddling around with " let ..  in " syntax right now, I think it should be solvable that way. 
My usage of "do" was completely incorrect, thanks for making me wiser!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you don't need `do`, `<-`, or `return` here. Those are for monadic code, but here you are defining a regular function -- there are no monads around.

So, we can instead use `let .. in ..`. Here's a possible way, performing minor changes to the original code.

```
func :: Int -> Int
func val =
   if val < 10 then let
      a = getVal0
      b = getVal1
      in if val + a + b < 0
         then 1
         else 2
   else if val > 10 then let
      a = getVal2
      b = getVal3
      in if val + a + b < 0 
         then 0
         else 1
   else 99
```

Many Haskellers would consider to turn the outermost `if`s into guards:

```
func :: Int -> Int
func val
   | val < 10 = let
      a = getVal0
      b = getVal1
      in if val + a + b < 0
         then 1
         else 2
   | val > 10 = let
      a = getVal2
      b = getVal3
      in if val + a + b < 0 
         then 0
         else 1
   | otherwise = 99
```

Comment: Totally helped me implement the problem I was stuck with, thanks a lot!